# What write concern uses mongoid gem (v3.1.4)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Context:
With Mongoid gem (v3.1.4) you can increase the confidence data is written when a write action is performed by using the *safe* attribute in the mongoid configuration file.

However, Mongoid documentation doesn't specify which MongoDB [write concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/write-concern/) is using, it only [says](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/tips.html#safe_mode) it's a good practice for beginners.

Question:
I need to know what MongoDB "write concern" uses the Mongoid gem (v3.1.4) when "safe" attribute is set to true and when set to false.

Comment: Did you read the "answer" [Default Write Concern](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#default-write-concern) further down that page? Default means unless you change it, that is what happens.

Comment: @NeilLunn, thanks for your comment. No, I didn't notice that part. I just edited my question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoid 3 uses Moped as its MongoDB driver. Having a look at Moped source code:

https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/1.5.0-stable/lib/moped/session.rb

- **safe: true** is equivalent to a write concern of 1
- **safe: false** is equivalent to a write concern of 0 (this is the default)

And you can also specify a number greater than 1 with:

```
safe: {w: 2}
```

Mongoid 5 no longer uses Moped:

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/announcing-ruby-driver-20-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

You have to drop down to driver level to change default write concern. Default write concern defined is 1. If you wish to set it to 0, you can do that "with" method on collection of Model instance.

```
collection_w_0 = Band.collection.with(write: { w: 0 })
collection_w_0[:artists].find(...)
```